# How do I keep Colab Pro+ background execution enalbed?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I purchased Colab Pro+ today, and tried running a model. However, it seems that the program pauses when I close the browser or my computer sleeps. Google website says that Colab Pro+ provides background execution. How do I enable it?

I justed tried closing my browser and leaving my computer alone to make sure backgroung execution is enabled.